# Attach a profile to User Entity UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony

I build my custom bundle for handle login/logout/register ([security](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/security.html)) works fine, I have three bundles and they all use the same security bundle but of them have a "profile" attached to the user.

which is the best way to attach the profile to the user without affect the security bundle or at least only for the bundle that need. Is there any interface profile within symfony?

Exist some way to make a relation with Doctrine2 without store in the database. make a relation OneToOne between profile and User without store (obviously the profile and user has data for check this relation but without foreign keys)

#### Update

I'm testing with inheritance but i dont wanna two tables i need only one, if i put the same table name i get a conflict i need only a user table. if i remove the Entity and add MappedSuperclass works fine for the the bundle but stop working for the others, i'll need extend a User for every bundle (i dont want this) how can fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [single table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) if you don't want to have two tables but still use inheritance.

*example User:*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User", "user_with_profile" = "ExtendedUser"})
 */
class User
{
    // ...
}
```

*example extented User:*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ExtendedUser extends User
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That creates an additional field in the user table?, exist a way without change the base class? if i have more user types

Comment: you could create a listener and adjust the discriminatormap dynamically if you don't want to touch the base user but that feels kind of wrong to me.

Comment: well then you're stuck :) ... why not just create a single user entity and use this one adding different roles/properties in your other bundles? or just add the support for your other bundle's entities to your user-provider dynamically with container parameters?